# Modifying a model attribute won't make it to the DB in Yii's CActiveRecord::beforeSave()

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I'm implementing HTML sanitization for form fields, on the beforeSave() method of a model. But it doesn't work.
Example:
`public function beforeSave()
{
  $this->anAttribute = 'somevalue';
  var_dump( $this->anAttribute );
}`

`somevalue` is actually outputted, but it never gets to the DB, so in between beforeSave() and save() the value is lost and what's saved is the original form field value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your line

```
public function beforeSave()
{
  $this->anAttribute = 'somevalue';
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that was it. Also had to call parent::beforeSave()

Answer (score 0):

How about using afterValidate() instead of beforeSave() ?

Comment: Do not user afterValidate() to store values, values will get updated before save it will produce some issues

Comment: Yes, actually there's a model that doesn't have validation, the user can enter whatever they want in any field, including nothing, but the input has still to be sanitized to remove HTML and therefore XSS.